# Planar Graph max min edges

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

Consider a planar graph with 5 vertices, what is the minimum and the maximum number of edges such a graph can have?
The graph need not be connected and is simple.

Comment: Are there any conditions on the graph other than it must be planar? If the graph need not be connected, the minimum number of edges would be 0. If the graph must be connected, the minimum number of edges would be 4. If the graph need not be simple, then there is no maximum number of edges. If the graph must be simple, then the maximum number of edges would be 9, since $K_5$ is not planar, but $K_5 - e$ is.

Comment: How do you get 9 for the maximum edges? Using what formulae?

Comment: The graph need not be connected and I assume is simple

Answer (score 1):

The maximal number of edges is 9. It is well-known that the number of edges a planar graph with n vertices can have is:

3(n-2)

In this case 3*5 - 3*(-2) = 15 - 6 = 9

Quote from wikipedia:

"If a maximal planar graph has v vertices with v > 2, then it has precisely 3v − 6 edges and 2v − 4 faces."

Answer (score 1):

$K_5$ contains $10$ edges and it is not planar (as $e\le 3v-6$ fails). A graph of $5$ vertices with $9$ edges would do as it won't contain a sub-division of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$. (See [Kuratowski's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem))

Answer (score 0):

Euler's Identity says, that for every planar graph of order n >= 3: the size m <= 3n - 6.
That gives you an upper bound of 3*5-6 = 9 edges.

Furthermore, since you said that the graph does NOT need to be connected, a graph with just 5 isolated vertices would do the job, it is obvious that such a graph is planar. Therefore, the lower bound would be 0 edges.